# nginx+uWSGI: dynamic vs emperor mode

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I am doing multi-application nginx+uWSGI setup and I wonder if I should use dynamic mode of uWSGI as documented [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#VirtualHosting) (under Dynamic apps) or the [Emperor mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html). I am slightly more inclined to use the emperor mode but maybe it is not the best choice. What are pros/cons of each?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emperor mode is for handling multi-application environments. It basically monitors the directories you specify for new apps & events you want it to respond to.

Pros:

- You can gracefully reload a site when you update your code by touching the vassal file.
- Apps respawn on crashes & reboots.
- Scales very nice if you need to add multiple servers
- Throttles your vassals to prevent Denial of Service (DoS)

Cons

- I'm not sure there are any.  I believe this is the preferred way to run apps (even if only one).

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe launching with the settings provided in the docs will only launch an app Nginx passes.  There are two issues I see with this, you're stuck with Nginx.  Not saying that's bad, but if you wanted to play around with, or decided to move to another server, you might need to redo the setup.  Also, this does not provide any of the benefits I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I see. Also the emperor mode is probably more flexible because there is separate master process and workers for each application.

Comment: Exaclty.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

The dynamic mode is only for people coming from mod_python, mod_perl or mod_wsgi in non-daemon mode that want/need a similar setup. For all of the other uses (i would say, 99.9% of the uses) the Emperor is the best choice. Take in account that only the perl and python plugins
support dynamic mode, all of the other plugins enforce you to the Emperor.